# Windows 10 command line: how to establish vpn connection without error 703?

Tags: networking, windows-10, command-line, vpn

I tried using `rasdial` many many times.

At some point I made successful connection: when I cleared saved credentials.

But at next day 703rd error were again. And addition/clearing credentials in settings does not helped.

Any ideas how to solve this disaster error?

PBK connection entry:

```
Encoding=1
PBVersion=4
Type=2
AutoLogon=0
UseRasCredentials=1
LowDateTime=358341792
HighDateTime=30648048
DialParamsUID=787105140
Guid=2BCE0037DD08E2418AED5B45C352CCC2
VpnStrategy=7
ExcludedProtocols=0
LcpExtensions=1
DataEncryption=256
SwCompression=0
NegotiateMultilinkAlways=0
SkipDoubleDialDialog=0
DialMode=0
OverridePref=15
RedialAttempts=3
RedialSeconds=60
IdleDisconnectSeconds=0
RedialOnLinkFailure=1
CallbackMode=0
CustomDialDll=
CustomDialFunc=
CustomRasDialDll=
ForceSecureCompartment=0
DisableIKENameEkuCheck=0
AuthenticateServer=0
ShareMsFilePrint=1
BindMsNetClient=1
SharedPhoneNumbers=0
GlobalDeviceSettings=0
PrerequisiteEntry=
PrerequisitePbk=
PreferredPort=VPN2-0
PreferredDevice=WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
PreferredBps=0
PreferredHwFlow=1
PreferredProtocol=1
PreferredCompression=1
PreferredSpeaker=1
PreferredMdmProtocol=0
PreviewUserPw=1
PreviewDomain=1
PreviewPhoneNumber=0
ShowDialingProgress=1
ShowMonitorIconInTaskBar=1
CustomAuthKey=26
CustomAuthData=314442431A00000008000000010000000000000000000000
AuthRestrictions=128
IpPrioritizeRemote=1
IpInterfaceMetric=0
IpHeaderCompression=0
IpAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDnsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDns2Address=0.0.0.0
IpWinsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpWins2Address=0.0.0.0
IpAssign=1
IpNameAssign=1
IpDnsFlags=0
IpNBTFlags=1
TcpWindowSize=0
UseFlags=2
IpSecFlags=0
IpDnsSuffix=
Ipv6Assign=1
Ipv6Address=::
Ipv6PrefixLength=0
Ipv6PrioritizeRemote=1
Ipv6InterfaceMetric=0
Ipv6NameAssign=1
Ipv6DnsAddress=::
Ipv6Dns2Address=::
Ipv6Prefix=0000000000000000
Ipv6InterfaceId=0000000000000000
DisableClassBasedDefaultRoute=0
DisableMobility=0
NetworkOutageTime=1800
ProvisionType=0
PreSharedKey=
CacheCredentials=0
NumCustomPolicy=0
NumEku=0
UseMachineRootCert=0
NumServers=0
RouteVersion=1
NumRoutes=0
NumNrptRules=0
AutoTiggerCapable=0
NumAppIds=0
NumClassicAppIds=0
SecurityDescriptor=
ApnInfoProviderId=
ApnInfoUsername=
ApnInfoPassword=
ApnInfoAccessPoint=
ApnInfoAuthentication=1
ApnInfoCompression=0
DeviceComplianceEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEnabled=0
DeviceComplianceSsoEku=
DeviceComplianceSsoIssuer=
FlagsSet=0
Options=0
DisableDefaultDnsSuffixes=0
NumTrustedNetworks=0
NumDnsSearchSuffixes=0
PowershellCreatedProfile=1
ProxyFlags=0
ProxySettingsModified=0
ProvisioningAuthority=
AuthTypeOTP=0
GREKeyDefined=0
NumPerAppTrafficFilters=0
AlwaysOnCapable=0
DeviceTunnel=0
PrivateNetwork=0

NETCOMPONENTS=
ms_msclient=1
ms_server=1

MEDIA=rastapi
Port=VPN2-0
Device=WAN Miniport (IKEv2)

DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber=****
AreaCode=
CountryCode=0
CountryID=0
UseDialingRules=0
Comment=
FriendlyName=
LastSelectedPhone=0
PromoteAlternates=0
TryNextAlternateOnFail=1
```